# Concerning the Zeros of $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

Is the Following Proof Correct?

**Theorem.** Given that $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces and $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ where $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ denotes the set of Linear transformations from
$V$ to $W$, then given any choice of basis for $V$ and $W$ the matrix of $T$ denoted by $\mathcal{M}(T)$ has at least $\dim\operatorname{range}T$ non-zero entries.

**Proof.** Let $\alpha = v_1,v_2,...,v_n$ and $\beta  = w_1,w_2,...w_m$ be arbitrary bases for $V$ and $W$ respectively. furthermore let $\mathcal{M}(T)$ be such that 
$$\mathcal{M}(T)=
\begin{pmatrix}
M_{11}&M_{22}&.\ .\ .\ M_{1n}\\
M_{21}&M_{22}&.\ .\ .\ M_{2n}\\
.&.&\ \ \ \ \ \ \ .\\
.&.&\ \ \ \ \ \ \ .\\
.&.&\ \ \ \ \ \ \ .\\
M_{m1}&M_{m2}&.\ .\ .\ M_{mn}
\end{pmatrix}$$
It is evident that $\operatorname{span}(Tv_1,Tv_2,...,Tv_n)=\operatorname{range}T$ and the spanning list $Tv_1,Tv_2,...,Tv_n$ may be reduced to a basis of $\operatorname{range}T$ consequently we have a linearly independent list of vectors $r_1,r_2,...,r_l$ where $\dim\operatorname{range}T = l\leq n$ and 
$$\forall i\in I=\{1,2,...,l\}\exists j\in J = \{1,2,...,n\}(r_i=Tv_j)$$

moreover since $Tv_k\cong\begin{pmatrix}M_{1k}\\M_{2k}\\.\\.\\.\\M_{mk}\end{pmatrix}$ (where $\cong$ indicates that the two entities are *isomorphic*), it follows that given the column vectors

$$\begin{pmatrix}M_{11}\\M_{21}\\.\\.\\.\\M_{m1}\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}M_{12}\\M_{22}\\.\\.\\.\\M_{m2}\end{pmatrix},
\ .\ .\ .\ ,
\begin{pmatrix}M_{1n}\\M_{2n}\\.\\.\\.\\M_{mn}\end{pmatrix}$$

we may find $l$ column vectors corresponding to every $r_k$ since each of the vectors $r_k$ constituting the basis of $\operatorname{range}T$ cannot be $0$ and so neither can the corresponding column vectors and thus $\mathcal{M}(T)$ has at least $l=\dim\operatorname{range}$ non-zero entries.

Comment: Yes, the proof is correct.

Comment: Another way- You know that dim range $T=$ rank $\mathcal{M}(T).$ Then show that a matrix has at least as many non zero entries as its rank.

Comment: Yeah i guess that too ! but the book i was using talks about rank later any way thanks !